# Popen - how can I differentiate between end of line and empty line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I differentiate between end of line and empty line with popen ?
The output contains empty lines.

BTW, is wait needed ?

```
  p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    while p.stdout is not None:
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        line = line.decode('UTF-8').rstrip()
        if not line:
            p.stdout.flush()
            break
```

Comment: First thing I can think of is this: you're not giving the process time to do its thing before taking its stdout.

Comment: An empty line is `'\n'`, not an empty string.

Comment: Generally, you should `wait` on your subprocesses, to avoid creating unnecessary orphans.